# Possible to get QDomElement from QXmlStreamWriter?

Tags: c++, qt, dom, qxmpp

I'm writing a small XMPP server using qxmpp. Now I want to create a QXmppStanza and present it (as if a client had sent it) to the server and my plugins using

```
void QXmppServer::handleElement(const QDomElement &element)
```

This function requires a QDomElement and not a QXmppStanza. The only XML realted function I found in QXmppStanza and its derived classes (besides parse(...) ) is the function

```
void toXml(QXmlStreamWriter *writer)
```

I don't have experience with XML handling in qt yet, so is there a more performant way than writing the XML to a string/ByteArray, use it as input to create a new QDomElement and return its documentElement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I have to accept it is not possible.

As stated in QDomDocument's documentation I always require a QDomDocument in order to work with a QDomElement (and other nodes):

> Since elements, text nodes, comments, processing instructions, etc., cannot exist outside the context of a document (...)

The QXmlStreamWriter doesn't have a QDomDocument, so I really have to create a QDomDocument (which of course must live as long I want to work with the element) and then parse the text (QDomDocument::setContent).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and was able to convert from a stream to a DOM element by doing something similar to what is shown below.

The first step is to stream to a byte array.

```
QByteArray data;
QXmlStreamWriter writer(&data);
object->toXml(&writer);
```

The second step is to set the content of a DOM document. The document's document element should be the DOM element you need.

```
QDomDocument temp;
if(temp.setContent(data))
    QDomElement element = temp.documentElement(); // do whatever you want with this element
```